# CKEDITOR Not able to add validate to input

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, jquery-validate

I am not able to add validate to this CKEDITOR ccontrol? I have this `<input name="editor1" class="required" id="editor1"></input>` and then I `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();` but it will not adding the required tag to this control , Any help would be great.

working sample
http://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/yhze8m1j/1/

js code

```
$('#add-job').validate({
    ignore: [],         
    rules: {
                editor1: {
                    required: function() 
                    {
                    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
                    }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                Job_Title: "Required",
                Job_Location: "Required",
                jobid: "Required",
                Job_Cat: "Required",
                editor1: "Required"
                },
                /* use below section if required to place the error*/
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "editor1") 
                   {
                    error.insertBefore("textarea#editor1");
                    } else {
                    error.insertBefore(element);
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: I have updated the post with the js code.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `input` and not `textarea`?  Did you do a search and look at the other questions?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate+ckeditor

Comment: I would like to use an `input`  if I change it I would need to add rows="1"

Comment: FYI - not going to fix your issue, but your HTML is not valid.  An `input` is not a container element.  It's supposed to look like `<input />`, not `<input>...</input>`